# How to apply CSS with jQuery and ignore hidden elements after filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a number of images that I'm laying out in a grid system of alternating sizes. For a number of reasons, the images have to start out as a default size and I'm changing each with jQuery depending on it's location. Here's a drawing of what it should [look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C7JW.png)

I'm also using jQuery to filter based on category, and would like the images to do the same thing once filtered. But, the CSS seems to be applied to the hidden images as well as the visible ones. I've tried using `.filter()` to just give me the `:visible` elements at all times, but haven't had any luck.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id='pagetop'>
      <ul>
        <li class="filter active" data-filter="all">All</li>
        <li class="filter" id='cat1' data-filter="category-1">A</li>
        <li class="filter" id='cat2' data-filter="category-2">B</li>
        <li class="filter" id='cat3' data-filter="category-3">C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="container" class="container">

      <!-- LR 1* -->
      <!--1-->
      <div class='mix category-2 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>ONE</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class B</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- BR 1* -->
      <!--2-->
      <div class='mix category-3 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>TWO</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class C</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- DR 2* -->
      <!--3-->
      <div class='mix category-1 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>THREE</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- DR 3* -->
      <!--4-->
      <div class='mix category-1 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>FOUR</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- LR 4* -->
      <!--5-->
      <div class='mix category-2 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>FIVE</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class B</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- LR 5* -->
      <!--6-->
      <div class='mix category-2 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>SIX</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class B</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- DR 6* -->
      <!--7-->
      <div class='mix category-1 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>SEVEN</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class A</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- LR 8* -->
      <!--8-->
      <div class='mix category-2 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>EIGHT</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class B</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- LR 9* -->
      <!--9-->
      <div class='mix category-2 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>NINE</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class B</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- BR 3* -->
      <!--10-->
      <div class='mix category-3 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>TEN</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class C</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- LR 10* -->
      <!--11-->
      <div class='mix category-2 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>ELEVEN</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class B</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- BR 4* -->
      <!--12-->
      <div class='mix category-3 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>TWELVE</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class C</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- BR 5* -->
      <!--13-->
      <div class='mix category-3 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>THIRTEEN</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class C</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- BR 6* -->
      <!--14-->
      <div class='mix category-3 mixlarge '>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>FOURTEEN</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class C</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- BR 7* -->
      <!--15-->
      <div class='mix category-3 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>FIFTEEN</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class C</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- BR 8* -->
      <!--16-->
      <div class='mix category-3 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>SIXTEEN</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class C</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- LR 11* -->
      <!--17-->
      <div class='mix category-2 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>SEVENTEEN</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class B</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- BR 9* -->
      <!--18-->
      <div class='mix category-3 mixlarge'>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?&w=668&h=337">
        <div class='longtext'>
          <p class='px32'>EIGHTEEN</p>
        </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
          <div class='text tC'>
            <p class='roomdesc'>Some Stuff Goes Here</p>
            <p class='roomtype'>Class C</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
* {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #pagetop {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .container {
      margin: auto;
      width: 1008px;
    }

    .mixlarge {
      width: 660px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 6px;
      margin-left: 6px;
    }

    .container .mixsmall {
      width: 324px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 6px;
      margin-left: 6px;
    }

    .container .mix {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .active {
      border-bottom: 6px solid #1F74BF;
    }

    .filter:hover {
      border-bottom: 6px solid #1F74BF;
    }

    .mixlarge .overlay {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      height: 337px;
      width: 660px;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .mixsmall .overlay {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      height: 337px;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .shorttext {
      position: absolute;
      top: 42%;
      left: 35%;
    }

    .longtext {
      position: absolute;
      top: 42%;
      left: 40%;
    }

    .px32 {
      font-size: 32px;
    }

    .mix:hover .overlay {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
      -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
      -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
      transition: opacity 500ms;
    }

    .text {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top: 35%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .text a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .roomdesc {
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 21px;
      letter-spacing: -.5px;
    }

    .roomtype {
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 16px;
    }

    .mixsmall img {
      width: 324px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .mixlarge img {
      width: 660px;
      position: relative;
    }

    ul {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    li {
      display: inline;
      margin-right: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #1F74BF;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .hide {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
   $('.filter').click(function() {
      var dataFilter = $(this).attr('data-filter')

      $('.filter').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      if (dataFilter == 'all') {
        $('#container').children('div.mix').show('slow');
      } else {
        $('#container').children('div:not(.' + dataFilter + ')').hide('slow');
        $('#container').children('div.' + dataFilter).show('slow');
      }
    });


    $('#container').find('.mix:nth-child(4n+1)').each(function() {
      var smallSize = 324;
      $(this).css('width', smallSize);
      $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');
    });

    $('#container').find('.mix:nth-child(even)').each(function() {
      var prevImg = $(this).prev().width();
      var rightSize = (984 - prevImg)

      $(this).css('width', rightSize);
      $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');
    })

    $('#container').find('.mix:nth-child(4n+3)').each(function() {
      var largeSize = 660;
      $(this).css('width', largeSize);
      $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');
    });
```

Here is a [link to a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesconroy/623n2yks/) of the work I've done so far.

So, I have the initial CSS working and I have the filtering working. But, I need a little help in applying that CSS to only the images that are scene upon filtering.

Comment: Toggle classes or data attributes on the visible/hidden elements so you can check the class/data attribute instead of checking element properties.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .filter, you could check to see if an image has a certain class, using https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

If the image has a certain class then make it do something.

Comment: Thanks. My hope was to just have everything with the same class, and to add CSS depending on the location of the image, rather than its class. This way, someone could add an additional image anywhere, at any time, and it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for .addClass()?
https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

For the filtering, you should check the :visible Selector in JQuery
details: https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/
There's also a :hidden

Complete list of Selectors for references:
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/